# Nodejs read csv file and insert to mongodb

Tags: node.js

I am creating a new endpoint to upload csv file and insert into mongodb using async. I want to read it from request instead of giving file path.

i have tried below code. but getting req.body.file is undefined.

```
        var lines = [];
        csv.parseFile(req.body.file)
            .on("data", function(data) {
                lines.push(data);
            })
            .on("end", function() {
                lines.forEach(function(data) {
                    // var teacher = await Teachers.find({ name: data });
                    // console.log(teacher);
                });
                console.log("end");
            });
```

Comment: how are you populating `req.body.file` from the client? input file or a textarea?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone input file

Comment: can you show the rest of your code? like the form, adding the upload handling lib, routes etc.. as req.body.file is not built into node, whilst if you're using multer it's in `req.file` or `req.files`, but you dont mention using that

Comment: @LawrenceCherone i am looking solution for upload file from client and convert to model